# I want to use flutter_blue_plus 1.5.2 and bluetooth_print 4.3.0 both plugin in single dart class?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

First I `import 'package:bluetooth_print/bluetooth_print_model.dart';` bluetooth_print plugin class then whenever I will `import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';` flutter_blue_plus plugin class that time I face BluetoothDevice class error.

I used both plugin in single dart class but I face BluetoothDevice class error so please suggest how can manage both plugin class in single dart class.

Thank you

Comment: define with alias. `import 'package:bluetooth_print/bluetooth_print_model.dart as blprint`. or whatever you name it.